# Xml Comparison in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to compare two Xml files using C# code.
I want to ignore Xml syntax differences (i.e. prefix names).
For that I am using Microsoft's [XML Diff and Patch](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3471df57-0c08-46b4-894d-f569aa7f7892&DisplayLang=en) C# API.
It works for some Xml's but I couldn't find a way to configure it to work with the following two Xml's:

XML A:

```
<root xmlns:ns="http://myNs">
  <ns:child>1</ns:child>
</root>
```

XML B:

```
<root>
  <child xmlns="http://myNs">1</child>
</root>
```

My questions are:

1. Am I right that these two xml's are semantically equal (or isomorphic)?
2. Can Microsoft's XML Diff and Patch API be configured to support it?
3. Are there any other C# utilities to to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got [an answer by Martin Honnen](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/3f2bb47f-356d-48f3-866c-b2533e5731f8/) in  XML and the .NET Framework MSDN Forum.
In short he suggests to use XQuery 1.0's deep-equal function and supplies some C# implementations. Seems to work.

Answer (score 10):

The documents are isomorphic as can be shown by the program below. I think if you use `XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces` and `XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes` to configure `Microsoft.XmlDiffPatch.XmlDiff`, you get the result you want.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace SO_794331
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var docA = XDocument.Parse(
                @"<root xmlns:ns=""http://myNs""><ns:child>1</ns:child></root>");
            var docB = XDocument.Parse(
                @"<root><child xmlns=""http://myNs"">1</child></root>");

            var rootNameA = docA.Root.Name;
            var rootNameB = docB.Root.Name;
            var equalRootNames = rootNameB.Equals(rootNameA);

            var descendantsA = docA.Root.Descendants();
            var descendantsB = docB.Root.Descendants();
            for (int i = 0; i < descendantsA.Count(); i++)
            {
                var descendantA = descendantsA.ElementAt(i);
                var descendantB = descendantsB.ElementAt(i);
                var equalChildNames = descendantA.Name.Equals(descendantB.Name);

                var valueA = descendantA.Value;
                var valueB = descendantB.Value;
                var equalValues = valueA.Equals(valueB);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IgnoreNamespaces is not good for me - I consider documents with different namespaces to be different semantically.

Comment: I understand, but it seems that XML Patch&Diff does takes namespaces into account when comparing, even when IgnoreNamespaces is used. I tested this with two documents <root xmlns="http://A" /> and <root xmlns="http://B" />. Diff&Patch thinks they're different. Unfortunately I haven't got the code with me now, so I can't confirm this 100%.

Comment: A and B in my previous comment were meant to be two urls but they were converted to links...

Comment: When I try it I get that they're equal

Comment: I get the same result you get. I think I made a mistake before. Continuing the investigation...

Comment: I posted an issue on Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=437072. I do not see any other explanation than that it's a bug.

Comment: They have escalated the issue, so it seems to be a real bug: 'We are escalating this issue to the appropriate group within the Visual Studio Product Team for triage and resolution. These specialized experts will follow-up with your issue'

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, it is all I needed. I have just added `if (!descendantA.HasElements) { var equalValues = valueA.Equals(valueB);
 }`

Answer (score 2):

I know that you're focus isn't on unit tests, but [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) can compare two XML files and I think it's able to solve your example. Maybe you could look at the code ahd figure out your solution.

Comment: Actually my focus is on unit tests.
However XMLUnit also seems to have similar limitations in .Net. It actually worked for the Xml's above but a slight variation broke it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an idea to load XmlDocument instances from each xml file, and compare the XML DOM instead?  Providing the correct validation is done on each, that should give you a common ground for a comparison, and should allow standard difference reporting.  Possibly even the ability to update one from the other with the delta.

Comment: It's an option - but it's doing by myself something which I believe to be a common problem with a common solution.

Answer (score 0):

Those documents aren't semantically equivalent.  The top-level element of the first is in the `http://myNS` namespace, while the top-level element of the second is in the default namespace.

The *child* elements of the two documents are equivalent.  But the documents themselves aren't.

**Edit:**

There's a world of difference between `xmls:ns='http://myNS'` and `xmlns='http://myNS'`, which I appear to have overlooked.  Anyway, those documents are semantically equivalent and I'm just mistaken.

Comment: That's incorrect. The top-level elements of both documents are in the default namespace. The top-level element of the first document can only be in the http://myNs namespace if it is declared either as
<ns:root xmlns:ns="http://myNs">
or
<root xmlns="http://myNs">