# How to get a collection of objects representing the diff between two XML texts?

Tags: c#, xml, diff

What is the best way in C# to get a **collection of objects** representing the **changes** between two XML texts, e.g.:

**First:**

```
<Customer>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <FirstName>Angie</FirstName>
  <LastName>Jones</LastName>
  <ZipCode>23434</ZipCode>
  <Contracts>
    <Contract>
        <Id>234</Id>
        <Title>Test Contract 1</Title>
    </Contract>
  </Contracts>
</Customer>
```

**Second:**

```
<Customer>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <FirstName>Angie</FirstName>
  <MiddleName>S.</MiddleName>
  <LastName>Jones-Smith</LastName>
  <Contracts>
    <Contract>
        <Id>234</Id>
        <Title>Test Contract 1</Title>
    </Contract>
    <Contract>
        <Id>534</Id>
        <Title>Test Contract 2</Title>
    </Contract>
  </Contracts>
</Customer>
```

**Changes:**

```
Kind:       Node:                  Before     After
--------    ----------             --------   ----------------
Change      Customer/LastName      Jones      Jones-Smith
Addition    Customer/MiddleName               S.
Deletion    Customer/ZipCode
Addition    Customer/Contracts[1]             <Contract>
                                                <Id>534</Id>
                                                <Title>Test Contract 2</Title>
                                              </Contract>
```

The point is to then pass the changes as a collection of objects onto a **GUI** which can appropriately **display** them.

**What is the best way to go about this, i.e. structure the class(es) that represents the changes and traverse/examine the XML in order to identify the changes most accurately?**

Comment: Also need to bear in mind changes in position - had the additional contract been at index [0], then would this need to be identified as an insert at [0], or as a change at [0] plus an addition at [1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a duplicate question for: [Xml Comparison in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794331/xml-comparison-in-c)

Have a look there, see if it helps.

Quote:

> I've got [an answer by Martin Honnen](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/3f2bb47f-356d-48f3-866c-b2533e5731f8/) in
>   XML and the .NET Framework MSDN Forum.
>   In short he suggests to use XQuery
>   1.0's deep-equal function and supplies some C# implementations. Seems to
>   work.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of work I have used [XMLDiff patch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295.aspx) provided by MSFT. It produces a [diffgram](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172088%28VS.71%29.aspx) which you can then represent as a class if you want.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to XML has a [`DeepEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals.aspx) method that I believe you can utilize in this case.

Then perhaps you can use the XSLT/XQuery processor called [SAXON](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) to get the differences.

Comment: XNode.DeepEquals seems to return a boolean telling me if the two XML texts are equal or not. Is there something similar that gives me a collection of the differences? Something like like "DeepCompare"?