# Compare XML snippets?

Tags: python, xml, diff

Building on [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794331/xml-comparison-in-c), how can one check whether two well-formed XML snippets are semantically equal.  All I need is "equal" or not, since I'm using this for unit tests.

In the system I want, these would be equal (note the order of 'start'
and 'end'):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
<Stats start="1275955200" end="1276041599">
</Stats>

# Reordered start and end

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
<Stats end="1276041599" start="1275955200" >
</Stats>
```

I have lmxl and other tools at my disposal, and a simple function that only allows reordering of attributes would work fine as well!

---

Working snippet based on IanB's answer:

```
from formencode.doctest_xml_compare import xml_compare
# have to strip these or fromstring carps
xml1 = """    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
    <Stats start="1275955200" end="1276041599"></Stats>"""
xml2 = """     <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
    <Stats end="1276041599" start="1275955200"></Stats>"""
xml3 = """ <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
    <Stats start="1275955200"></Stats>"""

from lxml import etree
tree1 = etree.fromstring(xml1.strip())
tree2 = etree.fromstring(xml2.strip())
tree3 = etree.fromstring(xml3.strip())

import sys
reporter = lambda x: sys.stdout.write(x + "\n")

assert xml_compare(tree1,tree2,reporter)
assert xml_compare(tree1,tree3,reporter) is False
```

Comment: `from formencode.doctest_xml_compare import xml_compare`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [formencode.doctest_xml_compare](https://github.com/formencode/formencode/blob/3a1ba9de2fdd494dd945510a4568a3afeddb0b2e/formencode/doctest_xml_compare.py#L72) -- the xml_compare function compares two ElementTree or lxml trees.

Comment: This function is incorrect, if you swap attributes order in xml it will return False.

Comment: @mnowotka not true, it does compare equal for _attributes_ in different order

Comment: @ian-bicking Great tool! Have you put a license on it, I can't seem to find any info on it.

Answer (score 14):

The order of the elements can be significant in XML, this may be why most other methods suggested will compare unequal if the order is different... even if the elements have same attributes and text content.

But I also wanted an order-insensitive comparison, so I came up with this:

```
from lxml import etree
import xmltodict  # pip install xmltodict


def normalise_dict(d):
    """
    Recursively convert dict-like object (eg OrderedDict) into plain dict.
    Sorts list values.
    """
    out = {}
    for k, v in dict(d).iteritems():
        if hasattr(v, 'iteritems'):
            out[k] = normalise_dict(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            out[k] = []
            for item in sorted(v):
                if hasattr(item, 'iteritems'):
                    out[k].append(normalise_dict(item))
                else:
                    out[k].append(item)
        else:
            out[k] = v
    return out


def xml_compare(a, b):
    """
    Compares two XML documents (as string or etree)

    Does not care about element order
    """
    if not isinstance(a, basestring):
        a = etree.tostring(a)
    if not isinstance(b, basestring):
        b = etree.tostring(b)
    a = normalise_dict(xmltodict.parse(a))
    b = normalise_dict(xmltodict.parse(b))
    return a == b
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer and should be accepted. This is the only answer that actually cares about crucial fact that order of fields in XML doesn't matter.

Comment: there are two things to consider: order of _attributes_ really does not matter. however order of elements is significant in XML, this code is for a special case where you don't care the order of elements

Answer (score 6):

Here a simple solution, convert XML into dictionaries (with **xmltodict**) and compare dictionaries together

```python
import json
import xmltodict

class XmlDiff(object):
    def __init__(self, xml1, xml2):
        self.dict1 = json.loads(json.dumps((xmltodict.parse(xml1))))
        self.dict2 = json.loads(json.dumps((xmltodict.parse(xml2))))

    def equal(self):
        return self.dict1 == self.dict2
```

unit test

```python
import unittest

class XMLDiffTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_xml_equal(self):
        xml1 = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
        <Stats start="1275955200" end="1276041599">
        </Stats>"""
        xml2 = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
        <Stats end="1276041599" start="1275955200" >
        </Stats>"""
        self.assertTrue(XmlDiff(xml1, xml2).equal())

    def test_xml_not_equal(self):
        xml1 = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
        <Stats start="1275955200">
        </Stats>"""
        xml2 = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
        <Stats end="1276041599" start="1275955200" >
        </Stats>"""
        self.assertFalse(XmlDiff(xml1, xml2).equal())
```

or in simple python method :

```python
import json
import xmltodict

def xml_equal(a, b):
    """
    Compares two XML documents (as string or etree)

    Does not care about element order
    """
    return json.loads(json.dumps((xmltodict.parse(a)))) == json.loads(json.dumps((xmltodict.parse(b))))
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem: two documents I wanted to compare that had the same attributes but in different orders.

It seems that XML Canonicalization (C14N) in lxml works well for this, but I'm definitely not an XML expert. I'm curious to know if somebody else can point out drawbacks to this approach.

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)

xml1 = etree.fromstring(xml_string1, parser)
xml2 = etree.fromstring(xml_string2, parser)

print "xml1 == xml2: " + str(xml1 == xml2)

ppxml1 = etree.tostring(xml1, pretty_print=True)
ppxml2 = etree.tostring(xml2, pretty_print=True)

print "pretty(xml1) == pretty(xml2): " + str(ppxml1 == ppxml2)

xml_string_io1 = StringIO()
xml1.getroottree().write_c14n(xml_string_io1)
cxml1 = xml_string_io1.getvalue()

xml_string_io2 = StringIO()
xml2.getroottree().write_c14n(xml_string_io2)
cxml2 = xml_string_io2.getvalue()

print "canonicalize(xml1) == canonicalize(xml2): " + str(cxml1 == cxml2)
```

Running this gives me:

```
$ python test.py 
xml1 == xml2: false
pretty(xml1) == pretty(xml2): false
canonicalize(xml1) == canonicalize(xml2): true
```

Comment: Had also this approach in mind and am searching for the drawbacks or whether this might really be the canonical way to compare xml documents... (pun intended)

Comment: I have been using this for over a year on a site I run that compares XML documents for version control purposes. It works fairly well but the c14n doesn't control for having the same child elements in a different order, so I sometimes still get spurious results.

Comment: Does c14n reorder childs? I would guess no... Do you mean the case where the same childs are present but in different order you would like a "no difference" result but this delivers "difference detected"? In my case order of the childs might be important. ;)

Comment: @michuelnik Correct. C14n doesn't not reorder children. And that leads to false positives in my use case, where I'm not concerned about the order of the children.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a DOM approach, you can traverse the two trees simultaneously while comparing nodes (node type, text, attributes) as you go.

A recursive solution will be the most elegant - just short-circuit further comparison once a pair of nodes are not "equal" or once you detect a leaf in one tree when it's a branch in another, etc.

Comment: This is the solution, I was just hoping someone had written one already.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about this problem, I came up with the following solution that renders XML elements comparable and sortable:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def cmpElement(x, y):
    # compare type
    r = cmp(type(x), type(y))
    if r: return r 
    # compare tag
    r = cmp(x.tag, y.tag)
    if r: return r
    # compare tag attributes
    r = cmp(x.attrib, y.attrib)
    if r: return r
    # compare stripped text content
    xtext = (x.text and x.text.strip()) or None
    ytext = (y.text and y.text.strip()) or None
    r = cmp(xtext, ytext)
    if r: return r
    # compare sorted children
    if len(x) or len(y):
        return cmp(sorted(x.getchildren()), sorted(y.getchildren()))
    return 0

ET._ElementInterface.__lt__ = lambda self, other: cmpElement(self, other) == -1
ET._ElementInterface.__gt__ = lambda self, other: cmpElement(self, other) == 1
ET._ElementInterface.__le__ = lambda self, other: cmpElement(self, other) <= 0
ET._ElementInterface.__ge__ = lambda self, other: cmpElement(self, other) >= 0
ET._ElementInterface.__eq__ = lambda self, other: cmpElement(self, other) == 0
ET._ElementInterface.__ne__ = lambda self, other: cmpElement(self, other) != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting [Anentropic's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23368371) to Python 3 (basically, change `iteritems()` to `items()`, and `basestring` to `string`):

```
from lxml import etree
import xmltodict  # pip install xmltodict

def normalise_dict(d):
    """
    Recursively convert dict-like object (eg OrderedDict) into plain dict.
    Sorts list values.
    """
    out = {}
    for k, v in dict(d).items():
        if hasattr(v, 'iteritems'):
            out[k] = normalise_dict(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            out[k] = []
            for item in sorted(v):
                if hasattr(item, 'iteritems'):
                    out[k].append(normalise_dict(item))
                else:
                    out[k].append(item)
        else:
            out[k] = v
    return out


def xml_compare(a, b):
    """
    Compares two XML documents (as string or etree)

    Does not care about element order
    """
    if not isinstance(a, str):
        a = etree.tostring(a)
    if not isinstance(b, str):
        b = etree.tostring(b)
    a = normalise_dict(xmltodict.parse(a))
    b = normalise_dict(xmltodict.parse(b))
    return a == b
```

Comment: You can use `dict_constructor=dict` option for xmltodict: `xmltodict.parse(a, dict_constructor=dict)` , so you should not need to use `normalise_dict` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [order of attributes is not significant in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-attrval), you want to ignore differences due to different attribute orderings and [XML canonicalization (C14N)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML) deterministically orders attributes, you can that method for testing equality:

```
xml1 = b'''    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
    <Stats start="1275955200" end="1276041599"></Stats>'''
xml2 = b'''     <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
    <Stats end="1276041599" start="1275955200"></Stats>'''
xml3 = b''' <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
    <Stats start="1275955200"></Stats>'''

import lxml.etree

tree1 = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml1.strip())
tree2 = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml2.strip())
tree3 = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml3.strip())

import io

b1 = io.BytesIO()
b2 = io.BytesIO()
b3 = io.BytesIO()

tree1.getroottree().write_c14n(b1)
tree2.getroottree().write_c14n(b2)
tree3.getroottree().write_c14n(b3)

assert b1.getvalue() == b2.getvalue()
assert b1.getvalue() != b3.getvalue()
```

Note that this example assumes Python 3. With Python 3, the use of `b'''...'''` strings and `io.BytesIO` is mandatory, while with Python 2 this method also works with normal strings and `io.StringIO`.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleTAL uses a custom xml.sax handler to compare xml-documents
https://github.com/janbrohl/SimpleTAL/blob/python2/tests/TALTests/XMLTests/TALAttributeTestCases.py#L47-L112
(the results for getXMLChecksum are compared)
but I prefer generating a list instead of a md5-hash

Answer (score 0):

What about the following code snippet ? Can be easily enhanced to include attribs as well :

```
def separator(self):
    return "!@#$%^&*" # Very ugly separator

def _traverseXML(self, xmlElem, tags, xpaths):
    tags.append(xmlElem.tag)
    for e in xmlElem:
        self._traverseXML(e, tags, xpaths)

    text = ''
    if (xmlElem.text):
        text = xmlElem.text.strip()

    xpaths.add("/".join(tags) + self.separator() + text)
    tags.pop()

def _xmlToSet(self, xml):
    xpaths = set() # output
    tags = list()
    root = ET.fromstring(xml)
    self._traverseXML(root, tags, xpaths)

    return xpaths

def _areXMLsAlike(self, xml1, xml2):
    xpaths1 = self._xmlToSet(xml1)
    xpaths2 = self._xmlToSet(xml2)`enter code here`

    return xpaths1 == xpaths2
```