# Testing XML Using TestMethod

Tags: c#

I want to test XML file and their attributes in Test Method. Every time the XML is generated differs the order of the attribute. I want to check the XML and their attributes value and are they repeating? can u please tell me the best way to do this.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two XML files & generating a third with XMLDiff in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590214/comparing-two-xml-files-generating-a-third-with-xmldiff-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

May be this one can help you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx

and a similar question I found on StackOverFlow:

[Compare 2 XML Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505681/compare-2-xml-files)