# How to use Visual Studio unit test to compare two XML files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

I need to write a unit test to confirm that when I modify an XML file I get a specific result. I could simply compare the input and output as strings, but I don't want to get failures if little things like white space between elements are different.

Is there a simple way to compare entire XML files in Visual Studio unit tests?

(I'm using 2012 if that matters).

Answer (score 8):

You could try [XNode.DeepEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals.aspx). Note that for Microsoft's LINQ to XML implementation the element `<foo></foo>` is not the same as `<foo/>`.

If you don't mind 3rd party libraries, you have [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) and [Altova XML Tools](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html).

Also, could be relevant: [Xml Comparison in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794331/xml-comparison-in-c-sharp).